# Error --- Unknowm chromium error -6

Tags: android, eclipse, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am building an app using phonegap and jquery mobile for android. I am getting an error 
  unknown chromium error -6...

I am not getting the exact source of error - 
but I got the error while executing below code

getList.js

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
    $('#getList').css({ 'color' : 'red' });

    $("#getList").live('tap',function() {
        $.ajax
        ({
        url:'/home/rads-infi/workspace/jsonobject.json',

            type : 'GET',
            data : {'category' : 'bollywood'},
            success : function(jsonObj) {
                    alert("success");
                    alert(jsonObj);
                    var sony_result = $.parseJSON(jsonObj);
                     alert(sony_result);

                      // $('#content-list').html(sony_result[0].active_at_date);
            /*$('#content-list ul').append(
                '<li id="' + sony_result[0].title
                    + '">"' + sony_result[0].title
                + '"</li>');
                               */
                            },
            error : function() {
                 alert("error");
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

getList1.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"                  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <head>
           <title>demo</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
                content=" application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />

            <meta name="viewport" content="width=screen.width; user-scalable=no" />
            <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; />

             <link rel=" 
            stylesheet" href="android-asset/www/media.css" type="text/css" />

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
          <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="getplaylist.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body>

<div data-role="page" id="page-home" class="ui-page">
    <div data-role="header" data-nobackbtn="true" class="ui-header"
        data-theme="c">
        <img alt="logo" src="/android_asset/top_logo.png" height="36"
            class="align-right"> <img alt="logo"
            src="/android_asset/sony_music.png" class="align-left"> 
    </div>
    <!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" id="content-manual" data-theme="a">
    <!--    <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a data-icon="home">Home</a>
                    <li><a data-icon="search">Contacts</a>
                        <li><a data-icon="info">Events</a>
                            <li><a data-icon="grid">News</a>
            </ul>
        </div> -->
        <div>
            <div data-role="button" id="getList">Get List</div>

        </div>



        <!-- /grid-a -->

    </div>

    <div data-role="content" id="content-list" data-theme="a">
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <!-- /content-manual -->
</div>
<!-- /page -->
```

Comment: Please make sure and keep one thing in mind => Full details are required whenever you ask question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Please add the code that forces this error.